# Testing Google App Engine Application's doPost() from Development Mode

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, servlets, development-mode

I am working on a Google App Engine Application, and I have implemented a servlet that I want to test.  Specifically, I want to call the `doPost()` method of the servlet, and check the results.  Is there any way that I can do this without having to re-deploy every time?

Currently I have to deploy to check it, which is very inconvenient.  If this is my (not actual) deployed URL:

> HttpPost postMethod=new
>   HttpPost("http://my_app.appspot.com/my_app/my_app_place");

However, if I put the development mode URL in the `HttpPost(...)` I get a `"Permission Denied"` Error.  Has anyone managed to do this before?

Comment: what url are you using for development mode? This should work just fine...

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyApplication.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997/my_app/my_app_place  I read that you have to change 127.0.0.1 to 10.0.2.2 for the emulator, but this retrieves me the contents of the MyApplication.html file from my servlet's doPost?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542939/android-emulator-connect-to-gae-on-localhost Here is a more recent version of my question, with some new things that I have found out.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't POST to your servlet locally via Java, would using a command-line tool such as [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) suffice?

```
curl -X POST [see cURL's man page for the arguments you need] http://localhost:8080/my_app/my_app_place
```

cURL's man page can be found [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you ar just testing the Servlet (and not the UI), it should be sufficient to use [HttpUnit's ServletUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/servletunit-intro.html).